# Lazy Intern, what to do

Tags: manager, internship

My team had a lazy intern, whom I referred.

My boss assigned both her and me the project, a difficult one involving lots of coding. I was also told that if she didn’t code, I would have to finish it off. For her entire time here, she never wrote a single line of code.

Essentially, I realized my boss and her, sent me up a creek without a paddle.

My boss is asking her to continue as a fall intern and may even give her a full time offer.

How do I bring this up to my boss or HR? I’m done picking up her slack.

Comment: Why is your boss asking her to stay on, when she hasn't written any code?

Comment: @mattfreake well, I wrote the code, which she copied, pasted, and made minor changes. Then she did 1 presentation on it with shallow understanding since everything was my boss’s words. But she told me my boss is offering her to work in the fall. I’m so done 

Comment: It sounds like you need to tell him *now* that you have written the code (and maybe have a reason why you didn't flag it earlier, if you think you should have).

Comment: @mattfreake Yep, will do that soon. I felt quite ashamed since I referred her here in the first place.

Comment: That's fine, we all make mistakes (there are questions on this site about referring people who turn out to be not good) but better to solve the problem before it gets any worse

Comment: If the intern never wrote a single line of code, you will need to inform your manager as it is your job to train the intern and report her progress to your manager. If your manager hires this intern as a full-time employee, and she could not write good code, then your manager will blame your for not reporting her real qualifications or lack of qualifications. -- On the other hand, if your manager hires her for positions not related to coding such as testers, PM, PO, etc..., then there is no need to worry about her inability to write code.

Comment: The purpose of an internship is to teach the intern useful skills, not to exploit them as cheap labor. If you do get some useful labor out of an intern, that's a bonus. Not something that should be expected.

Comment: Use something like Git(hub) so you can show your boss who wrote which lines of code

Answer (score 8):

> I was also told that if she didn’t code, I would have to finish it
> off.
>
> How do I bring this up to my boss or HR?

Just talk to your boss. Indicate that she isn't much help, that you understand you'll have to pick up the slack this time (as expected) and you will do the best you can.

If the deadline appears to be in jeopardy, discuss that.

Let your boss decide if they want to ask about the intern's performance. Otherwise, dont bring it up further. Havig her continue or not is obviously not your decision to make.

> I’m done picking up her slack.

No, you are not.

Any time a company brings an intern aboard, the expectations should be low. You were told that you would have to finish the project. So your boss gets to decide when you are "done".

Answer (score -1):

For the company, is the "internship" an unpaid position or an opportunity to capture cheap labour, or is it a real investment in their future workforce (i.e. something that generates a net loss for them)?

It's crucial to make this distinction because when the worker is being paid little or nothing, the only remaining justification for participating is if they are actually learning something valuable, and their reasonable adult economic needs must still be supported in the meantime (if not by the employer, then somehow).

Companies are likely to face lazy interns if the reality is that the intern doesn't want to learn but feels obligated to continue (quite possible given how over-educated youth is forced to be relative to the labour market), if they aren't able to learn (because the company does not arrange a stimulating situation that makes reasonable use of the intern's time), or if the intern feels they need more income to support themselves but aren't getting it.

Most internships are a massive attack by employers upon the wages of young workers - previous generations either left compulsory schooling to enter the paid workforce immediately (perhaps an apprenticeship, but only in their mid-teens), or at the conclusion of a graduate course in their early 20s entered a full-time permanent employment at self-sufficient wages.

I mention this to situate your friend's situation in context - and possibly saying something about your own.

In terms of dealing with the immediate fallout, I'd avoid assuming too much responsibility for your friend's output.

You've spoken for them in a small way by making the referral, but experienced managers will know to vest little in such referrals of social contacts, and not to assume that two people who know each other (and may even be close friends) have the same attitudes to work or competence in a particular role.

Most developmemt work is more efficient with one person than two (unless each contributes hard-won knowledge capital that the other doesn't have), because you can cut out all the communication and work at leisure. So I wouldn't assume it will be harder to do all by yourself.

If the only remaining issue is a sense of resentment at your friend free-riding your work, it's worth remembering that good work will still reflect well on you (not just your friend), and you'll be patted on the back for successful collaboration with an intern and even recommending somebody the company wants to keep (rather than creating a fuss and falling out).

You might mention later, at a relevant time, that you coded single-handedly and that your friend didn't add anything to the codebase, but it won't pay to act as if the crime of the century is occurring. Maintain a sense of proportion about the consequences, of which there aren't likely to be any.

I'd also consider whether you're having a professional conflict over the quality of code or similar. Your friend might know they aren't at your standard and won't be, and are graciously deferring to allow you to complete the code yourself and to your own design and standard - the alternative being either to battle with you over their input, to slow you down while they get up to speed, or to cause a crap result. If this were the case, it would completely undermine your accusation of laziness and change the character of their behaviour into something quite positive.

Comment: It isn't a good assumption that an internship is an unpaid position as that is being made illegal in more places and it is expected to be a paid position.

Comment: @JoeW, I said unpaid *or* cheap labour. It's not reasonable to think anything described as "internship" amounts to quality permanent employment for an adult worker.

Comment: That doesn't mean it is going to be free or super cheap either.

Comment: @JoeW, "not cheap" by what standard? By the standard of you buying a loaf of bread off the shelf, or by the standard of what value jobs need to deliver to adult workers to afford to look after themselves and their families?

Comment: Not cheap by the standard that you are paying the intern, and everyone that is assisting/training the intern instead of doing their normal work. An intern isn't going to be able to produce the same level, quality or amount of work as a normal employee and they are going to need more assistance that a normal employee would. It isn't just a simple matter of giving them a task and expecting to get results from it. This question is a perfect example of what hidden costs an intern can have as it involves a project that might not get completed.

Comment: @JoeW, what an intern produces, like any learner, is their own improved capacity to work later. You wouldn't really expect the employer to get anything valuable from an intern during the internship, only expense. The costs are not "hidden", they are self-evident to anyone who understands the proper purpose of internship, which is as a kind of employer-specific college for students. The employer has to pay because they are lengthening the non-work learning process into the stage of life where people are fully grown adults who expect to be earning and supporting their families. (1/2)

Comment: The reality of course is that most employers don't see it like this. They see it as cheap labour to get profitable work done, dressed up (craftily, in their view) as a student college. But most of them would do better to just hire workers on full wages for such real work, because with artificial internships, they force those who want wages to instead dress themselves up as interns to get pennies, and they mislead those who actually want to learn into thinking they're getting an internship when they're getting unstimulating work at low wages, and neither kind of intern will be motivated. (2/2)

Comment: That does not mean claims should be made that is is free (when that is becoming illegal in more and more places) or cheap when it has lots of added costs in other areas.

Comment: @JoeW, I said "unpaid or cheap", not "unpaid" alone or with any emphasis on unpaid. You've argued about what cheap means, and I've explained that the relevant standard is what workers usually cost and what it costs workers to live in our society at an age-appropriate standard (obviously an infant schoolchild requires less than a grown adult at an age to start a new family). As for what it costs the employer, you're looking through the wrong end of the telescope. Ten thousand is a costly loaf of bread, but it is a cheap adult worker, if work is being done.

Comment: Yes, I know what you said which is why I replied. Unpaid internships are quickly becoming very rare as it is becoming illegal to do so. Cheap internships are just a myth as internships do have a larger impact on a company due to other higher paid employees having to support the interns which causes a loss of productivity in other areas and paying employees to support them. I don't think businesses are unaware of any of these expenses and know what impact it has on them. It is even worse then hiring a new employee as you don't know if they will stay for the long term.

Comment: @JoeW, if unpaid internships have had to be actually outlawed to stop employers using them, why wouldn't employers of the same bent continue using cheap internships?

Comment: Again, the costs of an internship isn't just what you pay the intern and it also includes the impacts it has on other employees that need to help them as well as the projects they are working on taking longer to get completed.

Comment: @JoeW, I accept that. The costs are not limited to the wages paid to the learner, but the cost of diverting already-productive workers into reproductive tasks. It's the same as one can see that the cost of running a school is not just the cost of keeping the children, but also of diverting adults into teaching roles.